# attributing value to a variable(date) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, variables

I need to attribute a value to a variable and I'm in troubles.
Here is my query.

```
DECLARE @DATA DATE

SET @DATA 
IF (SELECT DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())-1) = 1 
    SELECT CAST((GETDATE() - 3) AS DATE)
ELSE 
    SELECT CAST((GETDATE() - 1) AS DATE)
```

I need to place a date like '2022-12-20' in the variable, that I´ll use in another part of a second query.

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression, not an `IF`; you can't use a logical flow operator in the middle of a statement (a `SET` in this case). Also for assignment, the syntax is `SET <@Variable Name> = <Expression>`; you are missing the equals (`=`) operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the value as part of a query using either a *case expression* or *inline if*, such as:

```
select @Data = DateAdd(
  day
  , Iif(DatePart(DW, DateAdd(day, -1, GetDate())) = 1, -3, -1)
  , GetDate()
);
```

Comment: Sorry about late anwer Stu... Thank you so much..
I did somenthing diferent today, and work well too:

DECLARE @variable DATE
`IF (SELECT DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())-1) = 1 
 BEGIN
  SET @variable = (SELECT CAST((GETDATE() - 3) AS DATE))
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  SET @variable = (SELECT CAST((GETDATE() - 1) AS DATE))
 END`